# Ansible yum_repository modules without python3

Tags: ansible

On the target machine I removed python3 and python and there is no python installed on my target box and the ansible yum_repository module still worked !

I thought modules require python3 ?

Answer (score 0):

There is still a python installed on the remote host. Recent Ansible will do interpreter detection, so as long as there is some python installed in the usual locations that could work.

`yum_repository` module writes out a file in `/etc/yum.repos.d` based on parameters. Such a task works on either Python 2 or 3.

In contrast, the `yum` module requires bindings only shipped with python 2, `dnf` module with python 3.

Comment: Use ansible instead to print what the remote module python is, as it may not be the first in $PATH.  `ansible -m python_requirements_info -a dependencies=os node1`

Comment: **@John Mahowald**  

So lets say I have a friend and he does a :`ansible node1 -a "which python3"` and returns 


  `server1 | FAILED | rc=1 >>`  
  `which: no python3 in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)non-zero return code`  
The yum_repository module in an adhoc.sh script should still work?

Answer (score 0):

ansible module yum_repository still worked even though I removed python and python36 with yum remove.
I guess the answer